# setEndIconOnClickListener method not found in TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

I am using TextInputLayout and TextInputEditText in my activity layout. Here is my xml code:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
   android:layout_width="@dimen/login_width"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/password_margin_top"
   app:hintEnabled="false"
   app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/password_toggle_drawable"
   app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
      android:id="@+id/my_login_password"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
      android:hint="@string/password"
      android:inputType="textPassword"
      android:nextFocusDown="@+id/my_login_login"
      android:padding="@dimen/field_padding" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

I want callback on clicking the password toggle icon. I found this on - [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout.html#setendicononclicklistener)

When I call this method from the text input layout, it showing the `cannot resolve symbol`.

Adding my code sample:
imported class: `import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText;
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout;`

Variable declaration: `private TextInputLayout passwordTextInputLayout;`

method usage

[image: methode pic]

All the end icon related methods are not accessible. Those methods are removed?

Edit: I just decompiled the TextInputLayout class and checked the methods, I couldn't able to find the mentioned method in it.

Comment: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/610

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya: I checked it, but ignoring the error and building the project leading to a compilation error. Is there any other way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was using the 1.0.0 version of the material library. The setEndIconOnClickListener method was introduced in version 1.1.0 (no stable version of 1.1.0 is released yet). So, I have used the latest beta version to fix my problem.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-beta01'
```